# Do snail shells increase the number of rounds with age?

Tags: zoology

Do snail shells increase the number of rounds with snail age?

Comment: I think my answer to [this question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/19972/age-of-shells-on-beach/19981#19981) can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Once secreted the shell cannot increase in size, so that the growth of the body is accompanied by continuous growth of the shell, i.e. by the gradual increase in the number of the whorls.

This also means that the topmost whorls are the oldest and the aperture marks the front of the new shell.